# Getting access to var/www

Tags: permissions, files, directory, mysql, php

Very, very new user to Ubuntu and I've been searching for a long time without finding an answer. Probably I've gotten the answer but I don't understand it all that very well so I thought I try this instead.
My problem is that I don't have a permission to the var/www folder that I assume is where my "localhost" should be. I don't know how to change the permission so I can change files and add. Nether am I sure if I want to. MY intentions are only to be available to view PHP in my browser. If anyone know how I can change my permissions or how I can view PHP else way I'll be very happy.

Running Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks!

P.S. As I said I'm very new so please take it slow :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, had you install a server as **lampp**? Is you did, the files sould be at some place as `/opt/lampp/htdocs`.

Assuming that the *htdocs* directory is on /var/www, you could change the permissions like this (in a Terminal, open it by searching **Terminal** on the Dash):

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www
sudo chown -R **yourusername** /var/www
```

You must change **yourusername** with the username you entered in the installing process.

I hope it works to you!

Comment: -1 for ``chmod``ing to 777. Not necessary and also makes file appearing as executables. Hard to revert it.

Comment: As I guess you know more about Ubuntu then me, I assume I made the installation wrong. I followed a guide so I guessed it would work. Could you guide me though uninstall and reinstall? or give suggestion guide? Thanks!

Comment: Did you install any software for the HTTP server such as Apache, LAMPP (XAMPP) or anything like that? I think that Ubuntu Desktop hasn't any server installed by default, so if you installed something, please tell me and i'll be glad to help you. Else, if you had not installed anything, I'm sure that someone could help you to do it :)

Answer (score 9):

First of all, you can see the permission of /var/www has,  by this command `ls -l /var/www`.  You will see like this (this only for example):

```
drwxr--r--  7 www-data www-data  4096 Jun 21 10:53 CodeIgniter
drwxr--r-- 11 www-data www-data  4096 Oct  2 19:49 eAdministration
```

`drwxr-sr-x` is permission status and `www-data www-data` is ownership status.  By default, when you installed for first time, ownership status is `www-data www-data`. The thing that you should do, add your username belongs to `www-data` group by this command:

```
sudo adduser yourusername www-data
```

After that, you should change the ownership to your username:

```
sudo chown yourusername:www-data -R /var/www
```

It will result in:

```
drwxr--r--  7 yourusername www-data  4096 Jun 21 10:53 CodeIgniter
drwxr--r-- 11 yourusername www-data  4096 Oct  2 19:49 eAdministration
```

Then, you should change permission to 755 (rwxr-xr-x) for directories, 644 (rw-r--r--) for files, and I do not recommend to change permission to 777 (rwxrwxrwx). As suggestion from **temoto** to ***make easier to be understand***, you can do this:

```
sudo find /var/www -type d -print0 | sudo xargs -0 chmod u=rwX,go=rX
sudo find /var/www -type d -print0 | sudo xargs -0 chmod u=rw,go=r
```

OR

```
sudo find /var/www -type d -print0 | sudo xargs -0 chmod 0755
sudo find /var/www -type f -print0 | sudo xargs -0 chmod 0644
```

To ensure that setting has been running well, you can try php code in /var/www.

Comment: With setting 755 recursively, all files will be set as executable. You don't want that, really.

Comment: Nowadays chmod recognise `X` permission as `x` for directories and empty for files. It's possible to run `find /var/www -print0 |xargs -0 chmod u=rwX,go=rX`. With added benefit of easier to understand permissions.

Comment: ERROR, no permission for my user (that was in *adduser* suggested), at `/var/www/html` I can not do `cat > test.txt` even with sudo!  (I used last options of `sudo find etc` also)

Comment: First, could you try to find what groups are your user belongs to? Try to type ```groups <username>```

Comment: There is a typo in `sudo find /var/www -type d -print0 | sudo xargs -0 chmod u=rw,go=r`, which will list directories (`-type d`) instead of files (`-type f`).