# I cannot mount the shared folder between host windows machine and virtualbox guest linux

Tags: mount, virtualbox, shared-folders

So in the setting of virtualbox shared folder, I already has the click the set-up: auto mount and make permanent. My shared folder is named as VM-share

Then I log into the terminal of guest linux to type in the following commands:

```
$ sudo mount -t vboxsf VM-share ~/share/
```

It gives me the following error message:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on VM-share,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

So I googled it and follow the instructions on this page: [Why do I get "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525243/why-do-i-get-wrong-fs-type-bad-option-bad-superblock-error)

to install both the "`sudo apt install nfs-common`" and "`sudo apt install cifs-utils`"

However,when I repeat the command "`$ sudo mount -t vboxsf VM-share ~/share/`" It still gives me the same error message as before. I typed in "`dmesg | tail`", the following is the message:

```
[    8.743003] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s3: link is not ready
[    8.745374] e1000: enp0s3 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
[    8.752152] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s3: link becomes ready
[    9.633147] floppy0: no floppy controllers found
[    9.633209] work still pending
[ 3128.376259] vboxsf: Successfully loaded version 5.1.16_Ubuntu (interface 0x00010004)
[ 3128.376457] sf_read_super_aux err=-22
[ 5762.008076] sf_read_super_aux err=-22
[ 6052.591669] sf_read_super_aux err=-22
[ 6138.926441] sf_read_super_aux err=-22
```

So How should I do to mount the shared folder?

Answer (score 17):

As of now (version 6.0.10 of VirtualBox) there are `make permanent` and `auto-mount` options for shared folder, also `mount point` (`At`) in GUI of virtualbox. For me the following worked:

1. On guest Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils`
2. Add shared folder in GUI of VirtualBox.
3. Restart guest OS

Folder on mount point specified in GUI was created automatically and `ls` showed files located on host Windows PC.

Comment: sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils helps me

Comment: I could see the sf_ folder in /media/ right after running `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils` along with `sudo mount -t vboxsf ...` did the job

Answer (score 8):

It turns out the reason that I could not mount is because I did not install the vboxguestaddition version. So if you follow the steps here:

1. https://www.howtogeek.com/189974/how-to-share-your-computers-files-with-a-virtual-machine/
2. Ignore the windows part above, then follows the step here to install the guest additon: https://virtualboxes.org/doc/installing-guest-additions-on-ubuntu/
3. Then the file will be automatically there, but you might come across permission issue, check this page : [https://askubuntu.com/questions/189200/getting-access-to-var-www.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189200/getting-access-to-var-www)

I hope it helps people who might come across the same issue as I did.

Answer (score 2):

cd to the /media folder and create a dir with the same name as the folder you created/shared in the host machine shared folder:

```
cd /media
sudo mkdir nameOfMySharedFolder
```

mount the folder with the following command:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf nameOfMySharedFolder /media/nameOfMySharedFolder
```

watch a video for full description of process
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I5cV0V7vLJw
p.s. the sudo may or may not be necessary